# How to check cron modified time?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, crontab

How to find `cron` job modified time in Ubuntu, For Example: when the `cron` job has been modified or changed.

Answer (score 0):

Crontabs are stored on the filesystem, and thus you can view their modification time there:

```
# View modification time:
root@gen1:/var/spool/cron/crontabs# ls -l
total 8
-rw------- 1 root crontab 1565 feb 12  2017 root

# Update crontab:
root@gen1:/var/spool/cron/crontabs# crontab -e
crontab: installing new crontab

# New modification time:
root@gen1:/var/spool/cron/crontabs# ls -l
total 8
-rw------- 1 root crontab 1562 feb  6 12:17 root
```